# Delay loading the navigation menu items

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a top navigation menu for my site. The requirement is to open a huge menu on click of each top navigation menu item. For the reasons of performance I would want to load the page and then in the background complete the loading of the mega-menu items. What is the best way to achieve this.

1) Can I load the user controls/web controls from java-script?
2) Is it better to have a hidden panel onload the get the JSON response from my service layer and render the HTML inside this hidden div?

Any direction or examples will be helpful.

Comment: I am working on a site right now which has about the same thing. If your dropdown/menu does not have heavy images then it's nothing to worry about. Mine has huge images so what we did was defer the loading of those images only to after the dom has loaded